# ERROR: for snl Container "8a97810cb23c" is unhealthy. ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project

Tags: docker-compose

after adding sentenses given below in my docker-compose,i got this error (ERROR: for snl Container "8a97810cb23c" is unhealthy. ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project)

```
depends_on:
    rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: Please, post your docker-compose.yml file complete. I need how have you defined your `healthy check` section.